# HTML and JS Conflicting Elements (MouseOver)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover

I'm attempting to have an element in my layout to change text and background colors onMouseOver, and then revert to their original state when rolled off. The problem is that JS doesn't seem to recognize the nature of my CSS.

The element (#sidebar) has these pieces of CSS code (code of the sidebar itself not relevant):

```
#sidebar ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebar li {
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #AFCEEA;
    border: 5px solid #195A94;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

And it looks like this, prior to OnMouseOver:

[image]

This is the JS I'm using to attempt the onMouseOver:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(myColor) {
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar li');
    sidebar.style.fontcolor = "#6588C7";
    sidebar.style.backgroundColor = "#6588C7";
}
</script>
```

With this implementation in the div:

```
<div id ="sidebar li">
    <ul><li onmouseover="changeColor('new color')"><p class="class1">writing<p></li></ul>
</div>
```

But it does this to my sidebar instead:

[image]

How can I get the color to stay in the little boxes?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the elements contained within the sidebar to change background and text color on mouseover, right? Why not just use the `:hover` selector? :)

Comment: Firstly, you should replace `document.getElementById('sidebar li');` by `document.getElementById('sidebar');`. `sidebar li` is not an id.

Comment: Also your HTML isn't valid, you don't close your `ul` element.

Comment: @C.RaysOfTheSun the color of the background and words would change separately, (the letter color when you mouse over the letters, and the background color when you moused over the background colors) instead of together, so I abandoned that approach.

Comment: @ElJackiste That was just an oversight from bringing the text to and from my code editor. It's there in my version. Not to mention that trying to edit the sidebar element itself affects the entire light blue part of the box, not just the parts near the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can really simplify your code by using `:hover` instead of `onmouseover`.

I am using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for `li` to make center alignment easy. You do not longer need to suppress the `list-style` because the list items are no longer displayed as a list-item.

You may no longer need `class1` for the paragraphs. I just kept them in.

```js
function changeText(myText) {
  //find variable on page called 'myContent' and give it var name display 
  var display = document.getElementById('content'); 
  display.innerHTML = ""; 
  display.innerHTML = "New content.";
}
```

```css
#sidebar li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #AFCEEA;
  border: 5px solid #195A94;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontal alignment */
}

#sidebar li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
/* Apply top margin to all list elements except for the first one */
#sidebar li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#content { 
  border-radius: 25px; 
  width: 750px; 
  height: 500px; 
  margin-top: 50px; 
  margin-left: 300px; 
  background-color: azure; 
  padding: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="class1">writing<p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="class1">games/art<p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="class1">music<p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content" onclick="changeText()"> <p>Content here.</p> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped. I have one more question, if you don't mind helping?

Comment: @KatK Sure, no problem. What do you want to know?

Comment: When I use the JS function to change the text onMouseOver (the main reason I was futzing with JS in the first place) it jumps up a bit in the box.
Here is the JS:
    function changeText(myText) {
            var display = document.getElementById('content');
            display.innerHTML = "";
            display.innerHTML = "New content.";
     }

Comment: Here is the corresponding CSS:
#content {
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    background-color: azure;
    padding: 50px;
}

Comment: @KatK I have added it to my code and as you will see, the text does not jump.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I think it's because the code for the text change isn't itself directly tied to 'li'. Instead, it modifies what's in 'content', which is further down on the page, and uses this code: 
<div id="content">
            <p>Content here.</p>
        </div>

Comment: @KatK I changed the code again and see what you mean. The reason for jumping is that the <p> is not included in the new content.
display.innerHTML = "<p>New content.</p>"; will prevent the jumping.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` accepts id argument, but you are passing it a selector instead. You may want to use `document.querySelector` instead. Query selector documentation:
[Query Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: That works for changing the background of the first box, but instead of changing when rolling over a specific button, it only changes the first one, when rolling over _any_ button. I also can't figure out how to change the color of the letters using this method.

Comment: @KatK So you want all buttons to change color when mouse rolls over any of them?

Answer (score 0):

Your div id is not correct. It should be like this:

```
<div id ="sidebar">
    <ul><li onmouseover="changeText('new text')" onmouseout="resetText()"><p class="class1">writing<p></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for something as trivial as this. You could use `:hover` CSS pseudo-class. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```css
#sidebar ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebar li {
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #AFCEEA;
    border: 5px solid #195A94;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#sidebar li:hover {
  color: tomato;
  background: #333
}
```

```html
<div id ="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="class1">writing<p>
     </li>
     <li>
      <p class="class1">writing 2<p>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

div id name is incorrect

```
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar-li');

<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeColor(myColor) {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar-li');
  sidebar.style.fontcolor = "#6588C7";
  sidebar.style.backgroundColor = "#6588C7";
 }
 </script>
```

and

```
<div id ="sidebar-li">
   <ul>
       <li onmouseover="changeColor('#ffffff')">
            <p class="class1">writing<p>          
       </li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you could do :

```css
#sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebar li {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #AFCEEA;
  border: 5px solid #195A94;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="class1">writing<p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeColor(e) {
    var sidebar = e.currentTarget;
    sidebar.style.color = "#fff";
    sidebar.style.backgroundColor = "#6588C7";
  }

  var li_elements = document.getElementById('sidebar').getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < li_elements.length; i++) {
    li_elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', changeColor);
  }
</script>
```

But a simpler solution is to remove the JavaScript and to just do it with CSS :

```css
#sidebar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebar li {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #AFCEEA;
  border: 5px solid #195A94;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#sidebar li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6588C7;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="class1">writing<p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```